# Equivalent to "viewDidLayoutSubviews" that is only called once?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am searching for a alternative for `viewDidLayoutSubviews` that is only called once.

I use this code to move the login out of the view:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    username_input.center.x -= view.bounds.width
    password_input.center.x -= view.bounds.width
    login_button.center.x -= view.bounds.width
}
```

I need to do this once, so that I can then move it in with a animation when `viewDidAppear`. This all worked great till I split my View into different subviews and now the function is called multiple times. I could't find any equivalent functions to this that is only called once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a boolean that turns to `false` the first time `viewDidLayoutSubviews` executes. I did this many times and it works just fine.

```
fileprivate var firstLayoutSubviewsTime = true

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if firstLayoutSubviewsTime {
        firstLayoutSubviewsTime = false

        [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest that. (Voted)

Comment: Ok, that is also what I am doing right now, but I thought there maybe a better and cleaner solution